# reading multiple pages from a rest client and creating a json file in java

Tags: java, json

I have a URI that returns 5 pages while I run it on Google Chrome REST API Client.

I have to write a code in java to read all the pages and create a JSON File. Simple solution is to give the page size(attribute) in the URI as 1000 and extract all the 5 pages. But, the requirement is that - I have to check if there is any "NEXT" keyword present in the result obtained after running the URI. And if, the "Next" keyword is found, I need to extract the link from that line and run it to get the result from next page.

## JSON file

```
{"PageSize":100,"PageNumber":1,"TotalRecords":423,"TotalPages":5,
 "Items":
      [{"CampaignID":1,
        "Created":"2013-10-23T23:00:00Z",
        "ScheduledDate":"2013-10-24T00:15:00Z",
        "Name":"Halloween Deals Campaign",
        "Status":"Sent",
        "Links":[{"rel":"self","href":"link1"}]},
        "Links":[{"rel":"self","href":"link2"},
        {"rel":
         "first","href":"https:xyz"},
        {"rel":"last","href":"link3"},
        {"rel":"next","href":"https://rest.emaildirect.com/v1/Campaigns/
                              All?PageSize=100&PageNumber=2"}]}
```

Comment: Hey Tanu, you need to show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Convert the Json into JavaObject using GSon and then check how many TotalRecords and the Total Page. Based on that modify your query parameter